# simple question about cohomology group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let's consider compact 4-manifold $M^{4}$ and point $P \in M$.
Then (use Mayer-Vietoris) inclusion $i\colon M\setminus P \to M$ induce isomorphism $i^{*}\colon H^2(M) \to H^2(M\setminus P)$.

Let's consider circle $\gamma \in M$ and their homology class $\left[ \gamma \right] \in H_{1}(M)$, such $[\gamma] = 0$ in $H_{1}(M)$. Is it true that inclusion $j\colon M\setminus \gamma \to M$ also induce isomorphism $j^{*}\colon H^2(M) \to H^2(M\setminus \gamma)$?

Comment: So, what happens if you attempt an analogous Mayer-Vietoris argument?

Comment: Hint: $\partial (S^1\times B^1)=S^1\times S^0$, $\partial (S^1\times B^2)=S^1\times S^1$, $\partial (S^1\times B^3)=...$

Answer (score 0):

So, this statement is wrong. Consider the exact sequences of the pair $(M,\gamma)$:
$$
H_1(M) \xleftarrow{0} H_1(\gamma) \xleftarrow{\partial_{*}} H_2(M,\gamma) \xleftarrow{j_{*}} H_2(M) \xleftarrow{i_{*}} H_2(\gamma)
$$ 
It is easy to see that $H_2(\gamma) = 0, H_1(\gamma) = \mathbb{R}$. So, $H_2(M,\gamma) = H_2(M) \oplus \mathbb{R}$ and by Poincare-Lefschetz duality $H_2(M,\gamma) = H^2(M \setminus \gamma),\ H_2(M) = H^2(M)$.